# Can't setup Wifi even though installing various drivers

Tags: drivers, wireless

this is my first question I am asking in askubuntu.com (Coming to my point).
As the title suggests, I have tried various drivers but nothing is working.
Various commands like `rfkill list all` and `lspci | grep Wireless`  are not giving any outputs. If anybody can solve the problem then please reply. I am panicking.

Some things to tell :-

When I do

$nm-tool

It gives me

```
Command 'nm-tool' not found, did you mean:

  command 'dm-tool' from deb lightdm (1.30.0-0ubuntu3.1)

Try: sudo apt install <deb name>
```

Also when I do

$lspci

It gives me

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v2/3rd Gen Core processor DRAM Controller (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v2/3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller (rev 09)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 05)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 05)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev b5)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 5 (rev b5)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 05)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation H61 Express Chipset LPC Controller (rev 05)
00:1f.2 IDE interface: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family Desktop SATA Controller (IDE mode, ports 0-3) (rev 05)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 05)
00:1f.5 IDE interface: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family Desktop SATA Controller (IDE mode, ports 4-5) (rev 05)
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 06)
```

$ lsusb

This command gives me :-

```
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 0bda:f179 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 008: ID 0489:c022 Foxconn / Hon Hai 
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 413c:301a Dell Computer Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Regards, 
Anik Nath.

Comment: Most important (in my opinion) is what OS & release you are using; as that provides detail as to the software stack you are using (ie. what kernel modules (drivers) are included).  For LTS releases there are two stacks offered (selected by which ISO you install with).  You've not provided any such details as to what you installed. How far did you get in troubleshooting, ie. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/WirelessTroubleShootingGuide  (the *Device Recognition and Operation* section is the most useful in my opinion, the details gained from that help us to help you).

Comment: Please edit your question to show the result of the terminal commands: `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3` and, if your wireless device is USB, then: `lsusb` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: @guiverc, thanks for replying to my question. I have Ubuntu 20.04 LTS installed and amd64 (I don't know what to tell this).

Comment: And another important thing, when I do ```sudo ishw -C network```, it doesn't recognises wifi adapter.

Comment: Providing the full output of the command can allow us to help you, ie. it may show UNCLAIMED (meaning it is recognized but is currently unusable).  Additional detail should be added to your question (not provided via comments)

Comment: Ok give me 12 hrs, I am doing a work

Comment: @guiverc, I recently updated the question pls check it.

Comment: @chili555, I recently updated the question pls check it.

Comment: `lspci` will only show PCI devices. Your wireless device is USB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Bus 002 Device 003: ID 0bda:f179 Realtek Semiconductor Corp.

Your device is covered by the driver rtl8188fu. With a working internet connection by ethernet, tethering or whatever means possible, open a terminal and do:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install –reinstall build-essential git dkms linux-headers-generic
git clone https://github.com/kelebek333/rtl8188fu
sudo dkms add ./rtl8188fu
sudo dkms build rtl8188fu/1.0
sudo dkms install rtl8188fu/1.0
sudo cp ./rtl8188fu/firmware/rtl8188fufw.bin /lib/firmware/rtlwifi/
```

Reboot and your wireless should now be working.

Comment: Ok I am trying to follow you instructions so stay tuned

Comment: I tried your solution and it finely worked for me. May god grant you long life and I feel ashamed of how I can thank you. :-)

Comment: I am very happy to hear it is now working as expected.