# Enter usb wireless E-W170 USB Adapter not woking in Ubuntu 20.04 but working in Windows 10

Tags: wireless

When I connect to the Windows adaptor name is "Realtek RTL8188FTV Wireless LAN 802.11n USB 2.0 Network Adapter".

Please help.

Comment: Search github.com for rtl8188fu

Comment: Please run the terminal command: `lspci -nnk | grep 0280` Is the pci.id 0bda:f179  ? If so, please check here and we'll mark this as a duplicate. If not, then edit your question to add the result. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1323860/cant-setup-wifi-even-though-installing-various-drivers/1324214#1324214