# Help install driver LB-LINK BL-WN151 wireless adapter for kernel 5.13

Tags: drivers, 21.10, realtek-wireless, adapter

I use Ubuntu 21.10 and kernel 5.13.0-30-generic.
I want to install driver of `LB-LINK BL-WN151` USB wireless adapter. And I want to use this adapter to create hotspot service.

My PC have a built-in wireless adapter but seems to be it does not have hotspot support.

`lsubs`

```
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 0bda:c821 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. Bluetooth Radio 
Bus 003 Device 005: ID 0c45:7663 Microdia USB Keyboard
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 0458:0186 KYE Systems Corp. (Mouse Systems) Genius DX-120 Mouse
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 05e3:0610 Genesys Logic, Inc. Hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0bda:f179 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL8188FTV 802.11b/g/n 1T1R 2.4G WLAN Adapter
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root h
```

`sudo lshw -C network`

```
  *-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: eno1
       version: 15
       serial: 8e:76:8c:f3:be:85
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=5.13.0-30-generic duplex=full firmware=rtl8168h-2_0.0.2 02/26/15 ip=172.20.6.69 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=1Gbit/s
       resources: irq:58 ioport:f000(size=256) memory:fe904000-fe904fff memory:fe900000-fe903fff
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: wlp3s0
       version: 00
       serial: 00:e0:4c:89:28:71
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtw_8821ce driverversion=5.13.0-30-generic firmware=N/A ip=192.168.1.69 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:67 ioport:e000(size=256) memory:fe800000-fe80ffff
```

`lspci -nnk | grep 0280`

```
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:c821]
```

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1335050/enter-usb-wireless-e-w170-usb-adapter-not-woking-in-ubuntu-20-04-but-working-in#comment2278614_1335050

Comment: @ChanganAuto Not RTL8188FU, I have RTL8188FTV

Comment: Run these commands with a temporary internet connection: `sudo apt-get install build-essential git dkms linux-headers-generic && git clone https://github.com/kelebek333/rtl8188fu && sudo dkms add ./rtl8188fu
&& sudo dkms build rtl8188fu/1.0
&& sudo dkms install rtl8188fu/1.0
&& sudo cp ./rtl8188fu/firmware/rtl8188fufw.bin /lib/firmware/rtlwifi/`

Comment: @Fakhamatia Same driver.

Comment: @ChanganAuto Its work fine